# How can I use "object-fit: contain" in CSS and still have a border radius on the image?

Tags: html, css, image, object-fit

I'm trying to show an image in a "lightbox" style so that it will fill the available area on screen, in this case 90% of the width of the page and 70% of the height.

Using `object-fit: contain;` seems to be the de facto way to do that but it's not quite working with `border-radius`. Is it possible to use object-fit on an `<img>` and still have the border radius applied as intended?

You'll need to resize your browser window to see what happens when you run the below snippet. I've got the [same code running in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe0m58du/63/), as per the below video.

[image: JSFiddle Video Demo]

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 70vh;

  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;

  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: Crimson;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/773/koldalen-4-1384902.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: you will need to shrink or expand the img tag itself, not what it renders : example : https://jsfiddle.net/6gw30rvL/ (grid display is only for the vertical-alignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `max-width` and `max-height` seems to be what you need or expect:

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 70vh;
  display:grid;

  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; 
  margin:auto;/* x,y center if inside a grid or flex box */
 
  object-fit: contain;/* useless by now, img should keep its ratio */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: calc( 5vw + 5vh); /* will scale, maybe you find this usefull */
  background-color: Crimson;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/773/koldalen-4-1384902.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: It took adding the `margin: auto` for me. This retained the `border-radius`!

Answer (score 5):

Contain isn't really helping here.

Instead, set the max width and height of the img to 100%. The system will fit it in either totally top to bottom or side to side, but the img element will have whatever dimensions it needs so the border radius will work on it OK.

To center the img, if that is what you want, you can `display: flex` the parent div and justify/align items to the center.

```css
div {
  margin: auto auto;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: Crimson;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/773/koldalen-4-1384902.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t understand your comment @evolross I’ve just tried it with a 200x 2000 image and it works fine. The image is the height of the container with rounded corners - of course it looks really skinny!

Comment: I didn’t set a static width or height for the parent container, just used viewport units as a demo, so I’m afraid I still don’t get your point.