# CSS contain an image inside a div and rounded borders

Tags: html, css

I want to contain an image fully within a `div`, and I am proceeding as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28526901/8849755), which works exactly as I want. Additionally, I want to add a border radius to the image corners, so I am using the property `border-radius`. However, after configuring the image within the `div` it stopped working. This is my HTML code:

```html
<div style="width: 50%; height: 77vh; background-color: red;">
    <img src="https://d3h1lg3ksw6i6b.cloudfront.net/media/image/2021/07/08/490b92922df3407cb5b91d3122a43579_Pavillon-Ledoyen.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 11px;">
</div>
```

How can I have the two functionalities combined?

Comment: Please include your current CSS too...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I edited this to mention that there is an alternate solution that does the effect you're looking for.

To strictly answer your question, it's not really possible to combine the functionalities of `object-fit: contain` and `border-radius` in the way you're expecting. When you use `object-fit: contain`, the image properly scales itself so that it can be fully seen within its container, but with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, it's still as if the bounderies of the `<img>` match the boundaries of its container (imagine that the remainder of the `<img>` space is taken up by an invisible fill, if that makes sense). In other words, if you examine the `<img>` in the devtools, you'll see that it still fills the entire container even though the colored part is constrained.

That's why `border-radius` doesn't really work as expected with `object-fit: contain`. It *is* working, but it acts on the entire width/height of the `<img>` that you see in devtools—it doesn't' know how to just act on the actual colored image part. If you take that CodePen and change the `<div>` aspect ratio so that it's only slightly wider than the image and then change the `border-radius` on the image to something large like 10000px, you'll better see what I mean: https://codepen.io/SonicBoomNFA/pen/vYbOqYR.

So it's not possible to combine the two functionalities, but as others have pointed out, there are other stylings you can use that will accomplish the task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77363975/22310659

Comment: Thank you. This explains a lot. I think it's possible, but we will need some some extra markup and extra css logic to it. Anyways when you explain the reasoning behind the problem, you can think up of a solution, thanks :) This is an actual answer to both of these questions including https://stackoverflow.com/q/68502752/11858171

Comment: @zerdox Thanks for that—I edited my answer to reflect that. I was too focused on answering why the original approach can't work and didn't think to figure out if there was a different way to make it work instead.

Answer (score 0):

Border doesn't apply due to the object-fit property. Remove it, and everything will be fine. To align the image, you can set the container to flex and adjust the image alignment as required.
But, the behavior of the image is now not configured, but you can build on this and think further.
P.S If you need object-fit: contain , then you can set for img width: auto; The behavior will be similar.

```html
<div style="width: 50%; height: 77vh; background-color: red; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <img src="https://d3h1lg3ksw6i6b.cloudfront.net/media/image/2021/07/08/490b92922df3407cb5b91d3122a43579_Pavillon-Ledoyen.jpg" style="width: auto; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 11px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution fails to contain the image within the `div` both in horizontal and vertical direction. If the `div` width becomes smaller than the image, it overflows. In my case it automatically contains the image in both directions.

Comment: Yes, that's what object-fit is for